# Adding superscripts and subscripts to kable table and ggplots

Tags: r, latex, kableextra

I having a rough time figuring out how to superscript and subscripts text in my plots and tables in R.  I just want to superscript the "-1" in the row "Units" below:

```
# Data for a table.  I want the "-1" in the units row superscripted.
df <- data.frame("X"=c("Unit", "Mean", "CV"),
                 "Total C" = c("g kg-1", 8.16, 5.94),
                 "Total N" = c("g kg-1", 0.51, 7.97))
```

The base function `expression` doesn't seem to work:

```
# I initially thought I would use a loop.
text <- matrix(df[1,])[1]
prefix <- substr(text, 1, nchar(text)-2)
suffix <- substr(text, nchar(text)-1, nchar(text))
# new <- expression(prefix ^ suffix)
# Doesn't work.  Literally returns "expression(prefix^suffix)".
```

I thought I would use `KableExtra` to create the table.  There appears to be a function suited for manipulating text (`text_spec`), but I can't find any resources on how to use it to subscript and superscript text.

[This Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52070416/kable-kableextra-add-superscript-to-group-labels-in-group-rows) seems to show how to use LaTex styling in a related Kable Extra function `group_rows`, but I can't figure out how to use it for my intended purpose.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limited usability, depending on how you'll be using the `Units` column but this works:

```
df <- data.frame("X"=c("Unit", "Mean", "CV"),
                 "Total C" = c(paste0("g kg", footnote_marker_number(-1, "latex")), 8.16, 5.94),
                 "Total N" = c(paste0("g kg", footnote_marker_number(-1, "latex")), 0.51, 7.97))

kable(df, format = "latex", escape = F)
```